# How to exit from function and addEventListener? return not working?

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

```js
let textList = document.getElementsByClassName('click');

let testFun = () => {
  for (let element of textList) {
    element.addEventListener('click', e => {
      console.log(e.target.textContent);

      if (e.target.textContent === 'TEXT3') {
        console.log('WIN!');
        return; // After this line I want the function to stop, but it still works. Why? And how to stop it?
      }
    });
  }
};

testFun();
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="click">TEXT1</p>
  <p class="click">TEXT2</p>
  <p class="click">TEXT3</p>
  <p class="click">TEXT4</p>
</div>
```

It is clear to me that this is the basics of JavaScript, but I have not come to a solution for hours.

The application I am writing is based on the manipulation of DOM elements. I need a listener for several elements at the same time and for a hit on the right element, I want the function to stop working.

Also, the break keyword doesn't work either because I'm in a function inside addEventListener.
So how do I solve this problem? Is there a mistake in the logic of the program?

Comment: Why should the `return` in function "3" affect the behavior of the unrelated functions "1", "2" and "4"?

Comment: @Andreas I just want the execution of the whole function to stop when I click on a certain element. How do I achieve that?

Comment: *"An example of the code is at this link"* Please put any runnable examples **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)), not off-site resources. Four reasons: If you do that, it's easy to forget to but all the necessary code in the question as well; people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` is returning from the event handler. No code in the event handler will run until after the `testFun` call has finished, if and when the `click` event occurs in one of the elements. Since `testFun` has already finished its work, there's nothing the code in the event handler can do to prevent that — it can't go back in time. :-)

You could remove the event handler from the elements (or just some of them?), though, so that they don't respond to clicks after the first click:

```
let testFun = () => {
    // Create the handler once
    const handler = e => {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
  
        if (e.target.textContent === "TEXT3") {
            console.log("WIN!");
            // Remove it from the elements
            for (let element of textList) {
                element.removeEventListener("click", handler);
            }
        }
    };
    for (let element of textList) {
        element.addEventListener("click", handler);
    }
};
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! The problem is in my way of thinking. I have to work on logic and ways of solving problems.